# Display foreach loop with certain ids first - Magento product list

Tags: php, sorting, foreach, html-lists, magento-1.9

I'm having many `<li>` elements in foreach loop with only two ids `bestsellers` and `not-bestsellers` in the following way:

```
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
```

How do I display elements with id="bestsellers" first and then not-bestsellers follows it?

```
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>
```

**EDIT**:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('bestsellers'); ?>
        <li id="<?php if ($attributeValue == 'Yes') : ?>
            <?php echo 'bestsellers';?>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo 'not-bestsellers' ;?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with same id.

Comment: Where do this `id` comes from? If it comes from Database, add sorting on it.

Comment: I'm sorting out magento product list with the following  <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should not have duplicate IDs, use class in instead.

Beside this, you could store the 'bestsellers' and 'not-bestsellers' in separated arrays, and then show them, something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('bestsellers'); ?>
    <?php if ($attributeValue == 'Yes') : ?>
        <?php $bestsellers[]= $_product;?>
    <?php else:?>
        <?php $no_bestsellers[]= $_product;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($bestsellers as $bestseller): ?>
    <li class="bestsellers">
        <?php echo $bestseller //or whatever you show here ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($no_bestsellers as $no_bestseller): ?>
    <li class="not-bestsellers">
        <?php echo $no_bestseller //or whatever you show here ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can check a working example [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3Cstyle%20type=%22text/css%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct.bestsellers%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctcolor:red;%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct.not-bestsellers%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctcolor:green;%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%3C/style%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20$_productCollection%20=%20array(%22Product1%22,%22Product2%22,%22Product3%22,%22Product4%22,%22Product5%22,%22Product6%22,%22Product7%22);%20?%3E%5Cn%5Cn%3C?php%20foreach%20($_productCollection%20as%20$_product):%20?%3E%5Cn%5Ct%3C?php%20(rand(0,1)%20==%201)%20?%20$attributeValue%20=%20%27Yes%27:$attributeValue%20=%20%27No%27;%20?%3E%5Cn%20%3C?php%20if%20($attributeValue%20==%20%27Yes%27)%20:%20?%3E%5Cn%20%5Ct%3C?php%20$bestsellers[]=%20$_product;?%3E%5Cn%20%3C?php%20else:?%3E%5Cn%20%5Ct%3C?php%20$no_bestsellers[]=%20$_product;?%3E%5Cn%20%3C?php%20endif;%20?%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20endforeach;%20?%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20foreach%20($bestsellers%20as%20$bestseller):%20?%3E%5Cn%5Ct%3Cli%20class=%22bestsellers%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3C?php%20echo%20$bestseller%20//or%20whatever%20you%20show%20here%20?%3E%5Cn%20%3C/li%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20endforeach;%20?%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20foreach%20($no_bestsellers%20as%20$no_bestseller):%20?%3E%5Cn%5Ct%3Cli%20class=%22not-bestsellers%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3C?php%20echo%20$no_bestseller%20//or%20whatever%20you%20show%20here%20?%3E%5Cn%20%3C/li%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20endforeach;%20?%3E)

Comment: I wish it could work find but this will have effect on the limits of showing products per page. I'd be appreciate if you could help me with the entire thing, http://pastebin.com/xaT6jDfR

Comment: I took a look to the code and I don't see how it will affect the limit per page...

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array(
        '<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="not-bestsellers">These are for "not-besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>',
        '<li id="bestsellers">These are for "besellers" products</li>'
    );
    sort($data);
    foreach($data as $value){
        echo $value."<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: use sort() method for short array either its id.... than put it into foreach and get desire output...